# Is that posible using BigQuery export a table data to a XLS file?

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

BigQuery supports exporting table data to `CSV`. However, I would like to export the results to `xls`. Is there any way to export the `XLS` format?

```
// Import the Google Cloud client libraries
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

const bigquery = new BigQuery();
const storage = new Storage();

async function extractTableToGCS() {
  // Exports my_dataset:my_table to gcs://my-bucket/my-file as raw CSV.

  /**
   * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
   */
  // const datasetId = "my_dataset";
  // const tableId = "my_table";
  // const bucketName = "my-bucket";
  // const filename = "file.csv";

  // Location must match that of the source table.
  const options = {
    location: 'US',
  };

  // Export data from the table into a Google Cloud Storage file
  const [job] = await bigquery
    .dataset(datasetId)
    .table(tableId)
    .extract(storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename), options);

  console.log(`Job ${job.id} created.`);

  // Check the job's status for errors
  const errors = job.status.errors;
  if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
    throw errors;
  }
}
```

Comment: google says for node.js : `npm install exceljs`  For python use `pip install openpyxl` and `df.to_excel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigQuery stores your data. When you export them, the data are exported, in CSV, in JSON or something else. It's the raw data.

What's excel format? It's raw data WITH additional metadata info to format the cells, have different sheet,...

BigQuery knows only the data, not the metadata that you want to add. Therefore, there is no built in feature in BigQuery to export to Excel (and the export to Google sheet is only a shortcut to export-to-CSV-then-import-data-from-CSV-in-Google-Sheet). You need to format your own file and therefore to code it. (same if you want to create a PDF)